# Monitor my siteminder application

Tags: siteminder

Is there any "out of the box" siteminder tool that checks if the siteminder server / application is runnig?

e.g. I send a request by a url like http:/mysiteminderapplication:myport/check_heartbeat.html and it responses me the actual status like ok, error, etc.

Sorry, I have never seen an siteminder installation but I have to check this fact for a customer.

thank you in advance,
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

You can use the One View Monitor to check the policy server status. It returns a lot of HTML though, you would need to parse the XML to get the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor smpolicysrv services by writing some scripts on siteminder server. As said above you can have oneView monitor too.
I have seen customers using Splunk Siteminder App.

https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/842/